# Why do the definitions of ADM-energy, -linear momentum and -mass make sense?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, adm-formalism

In asymptotically flat spacetimes, the ADM-energy, linear momentum and mass are defined as

$$E:= \frac{1}{16\pi}\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_{S^2_r}\sum_{i,j}\partial_ig_{ij}-\partial_jg_{ii}\frac{x^j}{r}\mathrm{d}\mu, $$

$$\vec{P}= (P^1, P^2, P^3) \quad\text{with}\quad P^j:= \frac{1}{8\pi}\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_{S^2_r}\sum_{i}\mathrm{tr}K\,g_{ij}-K_{ij}\frac{x^i}{r}\mathrm{d}\mu, $$

and $$m:=\sqrt{E^2-|\vec{p}|},$$ where $g$ is the induced metric on some spatial hyper surface and $K$ the second fundamental form of this surface in the spacetime. Given asymptotical flatness, these quantities are well-defined and behave as one would desire from these quantities under asymptotic chart transformations. My question is: why do these definitions make sense, i.e. why does an integral over some partial derivatives of the metric at spatial infinity resemble the total energy of the system, or over some terms with the second fundamental form the linear momentum? I know you can't define these quantities as in special relativity, but these definitions are really unintuitive to me.